# Prove that $f(x) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ does not has all rational roots

Tags: number-theory, functions, polynomials, roots

> The quartic polynomial $f(x) = x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$ is such that $ad$ is odd and $bc$ is even. Prove that $f(x)$ does not has all rational roots.

My attempt:

Clearly, $f(x)$ will have either 0 or 2 or 4 rational roots. Let us assume all the four roots of the equation are rational and they be $p_1/q_1, p_2/q_2, p_3/q_3$ and $p_4/q_4$.
As the question suggests:
a is odd, 
d is odd,
b is even/odd,
c is even/odd,
but, atleast one of b or c must be even.
$(p_1/q_1)*(p_2/q_2)*(p_3/q_3)*(p_4/q_4)=d$ (odd integer)           --(1)
$(p_1/q_1)+(p_2/q_2)+(p_3/q_3)+(p_4/q_4)=-a$ (odd integer)          --(2)
if --(1) is true,
the denominator of a root must be contained in the numerator of the remaining roots. This means, these numerators cannot have denominators containing a factor of their numerator.
So, there will be atleast two denominators whose gcd will be 1.
Thus, we cannot find any four rational numbers which add to give an integer  because rational numbers only give an integer if their denominators have atleast one common factor.
So, the equation cannot have 4 rational roots.
Same can be explained for 2 rational roots.

So, I just wanted to ask am I correct in my approach or am I making any mistake. Further, I am not able to understand why there is a distinction of ad and bc as odd and even??
Please help me out..

Comment: Why can't $f$ have exactly one rational root?

Comment: Also, it may help to notice that the rational roots of this polynomial must be integers (I am assuming $a,b,c,d$ are meant to be integers).

Comment: If f has a rational root, then the other roots will be irrational or complex which can only exist in pairs..

Comment: Even if the roots are integers, q1, q2, q3 and q4 will be 1. That won't make a difference to my solution. integers are also rational numbers.

Comment: @utkarsh, I think your language could be 'counted with multiplicity.' Then your statement would be clearly understood (and true).

Comment: @JohnMolokach Sorry, I didn't get you..

Comment: @utkarsh It is possible to have one rational root but it appears twice. For example $x=1$ and $x=1$ may be two rational roots counted with multiplicity, but it is one rational unique root.

Comment: @JohnMolokach The question says the equation does not has all rational roots. You may have 2 rational roots as suggested by Dietrich Burde.

Comment: @Utkarsh, I am confused.  Dietrich Burde's answer shows one unique rational root $(x=-1)$.  I am suggesting that a *repeated* rational root is also possible.  I think your language is a bit confusing.  Do you mean **prove that it is impossible for the equation to have 4 rational roots?**

Comment: @JohnMolokach Yes, this is what I mean to say.

Comment: @Utkarsh, in that case - kind of a hard question.  +1

Comment: @JohnMolokach you can see my attempt. I just wanted to know is my approach right??

Comment: Complex roots can only appear in pairs (assuming all the coefficients are real). But irrational roots can appear in pairs, in trios, in quartets, etc., etc. It's easy to find a cubic, with integer coefficients, and all three roots real and irrational.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is not possible for irrational roots to exist except in pairs( no matter how many) when the coefficients rational( in this case integers).

Comment: Please, Utkarsh, consider a 3rd degree polynomial with integer coefficients, irreducible over the rationals, and having three real (and of course irrational) roots. For example, $x^3-4x+1$. How do you propose to pair up those three real, irrational roots?

Comment: Do you agree, Utkarsh?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yep, you are correct. It's an equation that comes under Casus irreducibilis.

Answer (score 9):

For $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,3,1)$ we have $ad=1$ and $bc=6$, but nevertheless the polynomial
$$
x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 1=(x+1)(x^3+2x+1)
$$
has a rational root. Did I misunderstand something ?

Edit: Suppose that 
$$
x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)
$$
where we may assume that $a,b,c,d$ and all $a_i$ are integers. Then we obtain, by mulriplying out,
$$
ad:=-(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)a_1a_2a_3a_4.
$$
However, this shows that $ad$ is always even, because
every $a_i$ in the product must be odd, in order to have $ad\equiv 1\bmod 2$, but then $a_1+\ldots + a_4$ is even. This is a contradiction, so that not all four roots can be rational.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question.
the question says all four roots cannot be rational.

Comment: @Utkarsh I edited my answer. Now I do not need that $bc$ must be even. Is there a mistake ?

Comment: you have proved it for integers, but how to prove it by taking any rational roots(excluding integers)?

Comment: If you have a rational root $x=u/v$ with $gcd(u,v)=1$ you obtain $u^4+au^3v+bu^2v^2+cuv^3+dv^4=0$, hence $v\mid u$. But then, since $u$ and $v$ are comprime, $v=\pm 1$. Hence we can assume that $x$ is integral.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how is v=1 or -1??

Comment: Take two integers $u,v$ with $gcd(u,v)=1$. If  $u\neq \pm v$ and $v\mid u$, then $v=\pm 1$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how does v|u??

Comment: @Utkarsh Look again at the equation $u^4+au^3v+bu^2v^2+cuv^3+dv^4=0$. Which terms are divisible by $v$ ? You should try to find the answer now yourself !

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using the rational root theorem, which can be found here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Now, if ${p \over q},\ p,q\in Z,\ q≠0, \ gcd(p,q)=1, $ is a rational root of the polynomial $ \ f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \ $, then using rational root theorem, $p$ should be an integer factor of the constant term $'d'$. Since $'ad'$ is odd, $d$ must be odd too, and thus has only odd divisors, and since $p$ is one of the divisors of $d$, $p$ must be odd.

Also, by rational root theorem, $q$ should be an integer factor of the leading coefficient which is $'1'$, thus, $q$ is either $1$ or $-1$. Thus ${p\over q}$ reduces to $p$ or $-p$, as $q$ is $1$ or $-1$, where $p$ is odd. Thus if the polynomial $f(x)$ has a rational root, it must be an odd integer.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the polynomial $f(x)$ has all rational roots, where 'all' means 'four' here, because $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree '4', and thus has exactly 4 roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Now, by Vieta's formulas for relation between the roots and coefficients of a polynomial, the sum of the 4 roots of $f(x)$ must be $-a$, and $a$ must be odd as $'ad'$ is odd. But each root is an odd integer, and the sum of four odd integers is even, which contradicts the fact that their sum is $-a$, an odd integer.

Thus, it can not be the case that the polynomial $f(x)$ has all rational roots, and hence, we are finished with the proof.

Comment: Here, I have assumed that a, b, c and d are integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This answer adds nothing new to the other answer.